# Adding more items to page (pagination javafx)

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

i am using kotlin to create some small application with it, and tornadofx, however i am unfamiliar with how some of the javafx things translate to kotlin.

I am trying to itterate through a list of buttons, and add button to page, but i managed only to add one button per page, and i want to have X items per page, and i want page count to be dynamic

```
       override val root = tabpane{
    setPrefSize(800.0,600.0)
    tabs.removeAll()
    tabClosingPolicy = TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS
    val buttonList = arrayOf(
            Button("Btn1"),
            Button("Btn2"),
            Button("Btn3"),
            Button("Btn4")
    )
    tab("My Tab 1") {
        hbox {
            button("Click Me!") {
                setOnAction {
                    replaceWith<TestView>()
                }
            }
            button("Add Tab 2") {
                setOnAction {
                    tab("tab2 ")

                    {
                        select()
                        button("Close") { setOnAction { close() } }



                        pagination(buttonList.size) { setPageFactory { pageIndex -> (buttonList[pageIndex]) } }


                        style {
                            arrowsVisible = false
                            pageInformationVisible = false


                        }
                    }


                }


            }
        }


    }

 }
```

i tryed to implement a for loop that would add certain amount of items per page (lets say 2 buttons per page) and then proceed to create page. but i had no luck.
If anyone could help me find a proper solution for kotlin based pagination i would be thankful

```
pagination(buttonList.size)
```

with this line i can controll amount of pages, so that is at least something, but i dont see how to control amount items per page.

```
pageIndex -> (buttonList[pageIndex])
```

i realize issue is here, but i had no luck implementing proper logic.

lets say i want 4 items per page, i could get amount of pages required by dividing my list with number 4 (items per page). but not sure how to add more then 1 item per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SomeView : View() {
    private val buttonList = arrayOf(
            Button("Btn1"),
            Button("Btn2"),
            Button("Btn3"),
            Button("Btn4"),
            Button("Btn5")
    )

    private var pageSize = 3 //Decide this however you want

    override val root = tabpane {
        setPrefSize(800.0, 600.0)
        tabs.removeAll()
        tabClosingPolicy = TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS
        tab("My Tab 1") {
            hbox {
                button("Click Me!") {
                    setOnAction {
                        replaceWith<TestView>()
                    }
                }
                button("Add Tab 2") {
                    setOnAction {
                        tab("tab2 ")
                        {
                            select()
                            button("Close") { setOnAction { close() } }
                            //The ceiling calc is for rounding up for the size
                            pagination(ceil(buttonList.size.toDouble() / pageSize).toInt()) 
                                { setPageFactory { pageIndex -> createPage(pageIndex * pageSize, pageSize) } }
                            style {
                                arrowsVisible = false
                                pageInformationVisible = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createPage(startingIndex: Int, pageSize: Int = 1) : Pane {
        val pagePane = VBox() //Create and design whatever pane you want
        val endingIndex = minOf(startingIndex + pageSize, buttonList.size) //Don't go out of bounds
        for(i in startingIndex until endingIndex) { //Assuming starting index is in bounds
            pagePane.add(buttonList[i])
        }
        return pagePane
    }
}
```

Here is a solution for dynamic pages for pagination. Your main problem was that tab panes only hold one child pane/component. The answer is to nest your buttons in a pane. I haven't tested this hard for edge cases or anything, so this is more proof-of-concept. You'll have to account for those if they come up.

Side Notes: As explained above, this is also why your "Close" button isn't appearing. Also, when I was testing your code I noticed the style wasn't implemented unless I clicked a button in the pane. Maybe it would work if you used a stylesheet, created a cssclass, and added that class to your tabpane (Don't forget to import your stylesheet if you choose to do this).